# nonce on zend form

Tags: security, zend-framework, forms, nonce

Does anybody knows if there exists a way to use **nonce** in zend form.

*Note: The nonce field is used to validate that the contents of the form came from the location on the current site and not somewhere else. The nonce does not offer absolute protection, but should protect against most cases. It is very important to use nonce field in forms.*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [Zend_Form_Element_Hash](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html)